# BizTalk error: Routing Failure Report for "Routing Failure Report for "<Name is not available>

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, btahl7

I am attempt to send an HL7 message to BizTalk and getting an error code 0xC0C01B4e (Routing Failure Report) with the message:

> Routing Failure Report for <Name is not available>

I've had this working for the last day, and am now receiving this message, completely mind boggled.

My scenario:

```
1 Request/Response Recieve Port named HL7Test.In
1 Receive Location for the Receive Port called HL7Test.In.MLLP
   Type is MLLP
   Receive pipeline is BTAHL72XRecievePipeline
   Send pipeline is BTAHL72XSendPipeline
1 Send Port
   Type is file
   Send pipeline is Passthrough
   Filter is BTS.ReceivePortName == HL7Test.In
1 Party configuration called "REG", with the following BTAHL7 configuration:
   Acknowledgemnt type: OriginalMode
   Validate body segments: Enabled
   Validate custom datat types: Enabled
   Alow trailing delimiters: Enabled
   Schema namespace: http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X
I've deployed the BTAHL7V2XCommon, BTAHL7V21Common and ADT message schemas
```

I send an HL7 message using MLLP from a 3rd party application
No ack is returned
File is not written
1 non resumable error is generated, as described above.

The message I'm sending is:

> MSH|^~\&|REG|FAC|||201207271419||ADT^A04|504111|D|2.1|||AL|AL|
>   EVN|A04|201207271419||02 PID|1||M11||REGRIHSOT^xyz^2^3^5^6
>   NK1|1|Regrihsot^Wife^3^4^5^6|W|1^2^city^BC^V1S 0A7^6^7^8|
>   PV1|1|E|KAMRIHED|||||MITD4||||||HO||||ED||BC|||||||||||||||||||FAC||REG|||201207271417|
>   ZAD|MAIL^1^^city^BC^V1S 0A7|PHYS^1^^Kamloops^BC^V1S 0A7| ZTZ|PT|
>   ZGC|^^|

And this all worked fine an hour ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that I also need a send port that consumes the ACK.
I did have this before, so I added it using the filter:

> BTS.MessageType ==
>   http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X#ACK_24_GLO_DEF

What I don't understand is why I need to consume this message.

Comment: You should mark this as a solution, it saves me after spending half a day pulling my hair out.  What I find weird is, if you are the sender receiving the ADT, why do you have to handle the ACK.... shouldn't ACK be handle at the sender end? in any case, it works for me now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have too much experience with MLLP adapter, but in general any message that gets published into your BizTalk environment must have a subscriber. If no one is waiting for the message, then BizTalk treats it as error and throws the exception routing failure. This makes sense, since if BizTalk doesn't treat unsolicited messages as exceptions, over time your environment will get bloated with all those unsolicited messages.

I would have expected your MLLP request/response adapter should have picked up the ACK and closed the loop. Not sure why you need to create a separate send port to pick up the ACK. It may be worth investigating in that direction.

Comment: I expected in this case that the response part of the recieve pipeline would be the subscriber, but that is apparently not so.